# R: Efficient combine columns in matrix having same column name

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with columns that duplicate character column names.

I want to unique the column names and add value which with the same column name.

Like this:

```
   x y  x  y
s1 3 4  6 10
s2 3 9 10  7
s3 7 1  3  2
```

transfer to:

```
    x  y
s1  9 14
s2 13 16
s3 10  3
```

I have tried use sapply() function to do and it's work.

```
nms <- colnames(my_mat)
tf_mat_bind <- sapply(unique(my_mat), function(i)rowSums(my_mat[, nms==i, 
drop=FALSE]))
```

But because my matrix is 2756 x 431975. So it needs to take a "long time" to transfer.

I'm looking for another efficient way to do the process.

Comment: `t(rowsum(t(my_mat), colnames(my_mat)))` might be more efficient than your current attempt.